# Query multiple params through API Gateway with a Node.js Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am struggling to figure out the correct way to process multiple query params from an AWS API through to a Node Lambda_Proxy.

```
    res.a = event.queryStringParameters.meterid;
```

This is what I have to pass 1 query which works.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Add a minimal working example and show us the error message.